# Why global site-package does not see a local one?

Tags: python, python-venv, falconframework

I install python package using the system package manager:

```
apk add py3-gunicorn
```

Then I create and fill venv with falcon:

```
python3 -mvenv --system-site-packages .
. ./bin/activate
pip3 install falcon
```

No errors so far. But when I try to actually run my application,
I get following error:

```
[2021-07-25 14:36:37 +0000] [2] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4
[2021-07-25 14:36:37 +0000] [2] [INFO] Listening at: unix:/opt/xxx/sock/xxx.sock (2)
[2021-07-25 14:36:37 +0000] [2] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2021-07-25 14:36:37 +0000] [7] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 7
[2021-07-25 14:36:37 +0000] [7] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 119, in init_process
    self.load_wsgi()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 144, in load_wsgi
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 49, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 39, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 358, in import_app
    mod = importlib.import_module(module)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 855, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/opt/xxx/src/app.py", line 1, in <module>
    import falcon
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'falcon'
```

However, when I try to run

```
python3 -c 'import falcon'
```

it works. So it looks like the "global" gunicorn cannot see "local" falcon, but
I'm not sure why. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

So the answer actually is to invoke the gunicorn script using the python in the venv and not directly, so instead of

```
exec gunicorn ...
```

this

```
exec python3 /usr/bin/gunicorn ...
```